# HttpWebRequest - 405 Method Not Allowed - is what I'm looking for

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, error-code, http-status-code-405

I think I may be trying to do something a bit different from most posts on here.  Everything I find is someone trying to get around the 405 error code, whereas I'm trying specifically to verify that I get that error code as it indicates that my webservice is up and running and reachable.

I have the following code.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://andrewstxpd.tylermobileapps.com/TPSAlloy/Application.svc/execute-json/");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + " : " + response.StatusDescription);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode + " : " + response.StatusDescription);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        response.Close();
```

When I run it with http://www.google.com it shows me OK : OK in the console.

When I run it against my web-service address it hits an exception and errors out with 405 Method Not Allowed, but of course the stops the program.

How do I get that text from the error to actually check for it intentionally?

In other words, for me 405 Method Not Allowed is what I'm looking for specifically, so I don't want the program to end.

Comment: BTW, I can catch the exception, I'm trying to assign the error text to a variable that I can use to then check that it's the 405 I want.

Comment: And, got it. Noob issues on my part.  ex.Message.  duh.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can catch the exception with System.Net.WebException.  I then assign that to a variable such as 'ex'.  Then just use ex.Message to display it.

```
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred" + " : {0}", ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Done.